# Styling a fancybox iframe that is opened programatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am able to style fancybox iframe links with the following block of code:

```
$("#fancy").fancybox({
    type        : 'iframe',
    maxWidth    : 800,
    maxHeight   : 600,
    fitToView   : false,
    width       : '600px',
    height      : '590px',
    autoSize    : false,
    closeClick  : false,
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none'
});
```

Applied to a fancybox iframe link:

```
<a id="fancy" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="includes/schedule.php">link</a>
```

The problem that I am having is that the same is not working for a fancybox iframe link that I am opening programatically, within the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.submit').click(function() {
            var email = $(this).val()
            var varData = '&email=' + email;
            document.getElementById('beep').play();
            $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                    url:'mailer.php',
                   data: varData,
                success: function() {
                    javascript:parent.$.fancybox.open({href : 'includes/thankyou.php', id: 'thanky', type: 'iframe'});
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

The iframe is being opened with fancybox, but styling is just not being applied in this case.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your body element of thankyou.php page at the end.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#fancy").fancybox({
        type        : 'iframe',
         maxWidth    : 800,
         maxHeight   : 600,
         fitToView   : false,
         width       : '600px',
         height      : '590px',
         autoSize    : false,
         closeClick  : false,
         openEffect  : 'none',
         closeEffect : 'none'
     });
});
 </script>
```

Comment: I put that block in right before the closing body tag in "thankyou.php" but it's having no effect :(

Comment: can i have your site link ?.